# Name not found exception at PackageManager.GET_CONFIGURATIONS

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I'm trying to display `versionName` using below code

```
PackageManager pkm = getPackageManager();
PackageInfo pki = pkm.getPackageInfo("com.example", PackageManager.GET_CONFIGURATIONS);
String tempCurrentVersion = pki.versionName;
```

But I'm getting exception at `PackageManager.GET_CONFIGURATIONS` as `NameNotFoundException`

Please tell me how i can solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like it is necessary to use try-catch, to prevent NameNotFoundException error.
This solution works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728906/packageinfo-versioncode-and-versionname-null-on-phone-but-works-on-emulator .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this is my app and it works correctly.

```
String mVersion = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
    "com.safeneighborhood", 0).versionName;
```

If that doesn't work make sure your package name is correct. There
aren't any special permissions for this.

Comment: I get a compile-time error of `Unhandled exception type PackageManager.NameNotFoundException` using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

One really annoying time that I ran into this error was because the package name for the app that I was trying to find/intent over to had hidden characters in the text that I copied. Just to be careful retype out your package name or do a log to see what package name you are really looking for as it might not be what you think.